# Change pyviz node size when label is inside

Tags: python, visualization, pyvis

In `pyvis`, if a node has a label inside of it, then the node's `size` is determined by the label text inside of it. For example, if the `shape` is `circle`, then the size parameter is not taken into account. If the `shape` is `dot`, then the size parameter is taken into account. Is there a way that a node shaped like, e.g. a circle, can have the label inside and also have its size changed?